# Docker - ERROR: failed to register layer: symlink

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm running a docker-compose file we have, I usually run it with command:

```
docker-compose up
```

But today I'm getting this error.

```
ERROR: failed to register layer: symlink ../bdf441e8145a625c4ab289f13ac2274b37d35475b97680f50b7eccda4328f973/diff /var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/7O5XKRTJV6RMTXBV5DTPDOHYNX: no such file or directory
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker error when pulling Java 8 image - "failed to register layer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35325103/docker-error-when-pulling-java-8-image-failed-to-register-layer)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Followed this answer just restarting docker fixed the problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35325477/4031815

Answer (score 35):

[image]

To solve this issue, you just Stop and Start docker service from terminal.

```
# service docker stop
# service docker start
```

Answer (score 28):

For me, this issue came up when I tried to clear the `lib/docker/overlay` folder by deleting all its contents (not a good thing to do). After that, I was not able to build any of my images back.

Solved it by running this

```
docker system prune --volumes -a
```

Warning: This removes all the volumes and its contents which may result in data loss. Which was fine for me since I already deleted everything.

Comment: In my case, that also happened because I deleted the `overlay2` and `containers` folders. But it seems that I also needed to remove the `image/overlay2` folder that has the image database.

Comment: This answer plus @gearcoded's comment saved me, thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

Restart docker or if that doesn't work, do a Docker > Reset > Remove all Data.

I got the same error and the latter is the only thing that ended up working for me.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me and did not involve losing all my data:

- Make sure all docker containers are down: `docker compose down`
- Remove problematic overlay2: `sudo rm -R /var/lib/docker/overlay2`
- Remove images: `sudo rm -R /var/lib/docker/image`
- Clear any other cached data: `docker system prune -f`
- Restart docker service: `systemctl restart docker`
- Close and reopen any editor you might be using to run these commands (e.g. VS Code)
- Then, `docker compose build` finally worked fine for me

Comment: I am pretty sure, that closing and opening VS Code has no relevance here. For example, I don't have it installed, but docker is installed.

Comment: @alexander It was necessary for me, so I will definitely not say it is not relevant. But I've updated the steps.