# How to fix this annoying docker error? (failed to register layer)

Tags: docker

This error appears when I try to press ANY docker image.

This is a Fresh installation of docker in `5.0.21-rt14-MANJARO`

```
Unable to find image 'ubuntu:16.04' locally
16.04: Pulling from library/ubuntu
35b42117c431: Extracting [==================================================>]  43.84MB/43.84MB
ad9c569a8d98: Download complete 
293b44f45162: Download complete 
0c175077525d: Download complete 
docker: failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): Error cleaning up after pivot: remove /.pivot_root336598748: device or resource busy.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Comment: potential duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35325103/docker-error-when-pulling-java-8-image-failed-to-register-layer/35325477#35325477

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same error with the 5.0.xxx Kernel. Switching back to 4.19.59-1-MANJARO solved the problem...

**EDIT:**

you might try:

```
sudo tee /etc/modules-load.d/loop.conf <<< "loop"
sudo modprobe loop
```

then reboot and try again.

I'm now on `5.2.4-1-MANJARO`
 and everything works. 
I followed these instructions here:
https://linuxhint.com/docker_arch_linux/

Comment: I had the same issue on Manjaro with 4.19.152-1. Multiple restarts and reinstalls of docker to no avail. Failed even for docker run hello-world. Upgrading to 5.4.72-1 (as the next LTS kernel) fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the problem is with your kernel version. I installed the version 5.2.4 and works very well.

Version with problem: 5.0.21